# How to swap two matrices in constant time in C?

Tags: c

Currently, I'm using the iterative method of swapping element by element which seems to be very inefficient. Is it possible to swap two 2D arrays in constant time?

```
int a[20][100];
int b[20][100];
```

I want to swap `a` & `b` in **O(1)**.

Also, can the same solution be applied if I want to just override `b` to `a`?

Below is the code I used to iteratively override 'a' with 'b'.

Below code is used to override a with b:

```
for(x = 0;x<row;x++){
    for(y=0;y<col;y++){ 
       a[x][y] = b[x][y];
    }
}
```

Below is the code I used to swap a and b:

```
for(x = 0;x<row;x++){
    for(y=0;y<col;y++){ 
       temp = a[x][y];
       a[x][y] = b[x][y];
       b[x][y] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: C or c++? Pick one!

Comment: would swapping the pointers be valid solution?

Comment: I tried using swap() in c++. But it was complaining about "no matching function". I used swap(a,b);

Comment: You need to transfer 2 * row * column bytes, so the best algorithm can still be only **O(n^2)**. This doesn't apply, obviously, when you can only swap pointer, which is doable in constant time, but whether swapping pointers is sufficient or not depends on your use case.

Comment: @user3243499: if this swap worked, can you assume that it works in constant time ?

Comment: Yes. Basically, what I need is to update "b" using "a" and then overide "a" by "b". Then repeat.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: 1) "I'm using the iterative method of swapping element by element" is not posted which does not bring clarity to aspects of this post.  2)  If the array size is fixed, certainly your unposted code ran in O(1), constant time.

Comment: @AhmedMasud Updated with my code. It's a very trivial code. And that's the reason I haven't put and just said that I have iterated through each value.

Comment: @chux updated with my code.

Comment: Given the matrices are fixed size, *any* algorithm on swapping them will be `O(1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to swap two 2D arrays in constant time?

To swap 2 2D arrays `A[N][M],B[N][M]` takes O(N*M) time.  This is constant time only if `N` and `M` are constant.

The alternative strategy is for code to swap pointers to the arrays.

```
int main(void) {
  size_t N = 3, M = 4;
  // ...
  int A[N][M];
  memset(A, 1, sizeof A);
  int B[N][M];
  memset(B, 2, sizeof B);

  int (*Ap)[N][M] = &A;
  int (*Bp)[N][M] = &B;
  printf("A:%x %x B:%x %x \n", (*Ap)[0][0], (*Ap)[N-1][M-1], (*Bp)[0][0], (*Bp)[N-1][M-1]);

  // Swap pointers in O(1)
  int (*t)[N][M] = Ap;
  Ap = Bp;
  Bp = t;

  printf("A:%x %x B:%x %x \n", (*Ap)[0][0], (*Ap)[N-1][M-1], (*Bp)[0][0], (*Bp)[N-1][M-1]);
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
A:1010101 1010101 B:2020202 2020202 
A:2020202 2020202 B:1010101 1010101
```

Comment: And what if I try to override instead of swapping A with B ? In that case I think we need to iterate through every values as merely changing pointrs won't override any actual values.

Comment: @user3243499 Note this code does not swap `A` and `B`, it swaps a pointer to `A` with a pointer to `B`.  "Overriding" as per your post, destroys the original contents of `A` and is not a substitute for swapping.

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to store them as pointers.   For example:

```
int a_store[20][100];
int b_store[20][100];

int (*a)[20][100] = &a_store;
int (*b)[20][100] = &b_store;
```

Now it's easy to swap them.  You could also allocate them on the heap, or use `std::vector` in C++.

Comment: Do I need to iterate through all the 20 rows and then swap using a and b pointers ? Or can I use swap(a,b) directly to swap.

Comment: @user3243499 `swap()` is not a standard C library function.  `swap(a,b)`, as a _function_, will not work to swap `a` and `b`.